# How to limit IAM user access to an S3 bucket from a VPN connection only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

As the question says, we need to allow access to an S3 bucket to a user via specific public ip only and for that, we have applied an IAM role to the user as below. Still, we are not able to access that bucket content from the S3 browser extension.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/*",
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "13.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help to achieve that.

### =========================UPDATE=========================

As per the suggestion from @Dennistraub we have modified the policy and configured a cloudtrail data events on the desired bucket. Below are the details.

**NON WORKING SCENARIO**

The modified IAM policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "13.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Cloud trail event log for **Non-Working** scenario **with VPN connection** is as below

```
{
      "eventVersion": "1.07",
      "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "AIDAZSCHXUU7OI4HIXXXX",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::65728044XXXX:user/s3_log_user",
        "accountId": "65728044XXXX",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAZSCHXUU7P5Z5XXXX",
        "userName": "s3_log_user"
      },
      "eventTime": "2020-05-26T05:37:44Z",
      "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName": "ListObjects",
      "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-1",
      "sourceIPAddress": "17.225.XXX.XXX",
      "userAgent": "[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36]",
      "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
      "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
      "requestParameters": {
        "list-type": "2",
        "bucketName": "marketplace-logs",
        "encoding-type": "url",
        "max-keys": "100",
        "prefix": "",
        "delimiter": "/",
        "Host": "marketplace-logs.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "responseElements": null,
      "additionalEventData": {
        "SignatureVersion": "SigV4",
        "CipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "bytesTransferredIn": 0,
        "AuthenticationMethod": "AuthHeader",
        "x-amz-id-2": "TJg0h0KwFF3tggz6p4wit8Gsw+pMhZdTn2H4IMp/q1CY057Jdp3xzPjINIkwR1e1VOcCGt9XXXXX",
        "bytesTransferredOut": 243
      },
      "requestID": "F1D6946A8144XXXX",
      "eventID": "fb2ecf2a-df7c-476b-99de-631d486cXXXX",
      "readOnly": true,
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
          "ARNPrefix": "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/"
        },
        {
          "accountId": "65728044XXXX",
          "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
          "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs"
        }
      ],
      "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
      "managementEvent": false,
      "recipientAccountId": "65728044XXXX",
      "vpcEndpointId": "vpce-7d95XXXX",
      "eventCategory": "Data"
    }
```

**WORKING SCENARIO**

The modified IAM policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "182.69.XXX.XXX/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Cloud trail event log for **Working** scenario **without VPN connection** is as below

```
{
      "eventVersion": "1.07",
      "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "AIDAZSCHXUU7OI4HIXXXX",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::65728044XXXX:user/s3_log_user",
        "accountId": "65728044XXXX",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAZSCHXUU7P5Z5XXXX",
        "userName": "s3_log_user"
      },
      "eventTime": "2020-05-26T06:37:27Z",
      "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName": "ListObjects",
      "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-1",
      "sourceIPAddress": "182.69.XXX.XXX",
      "userAgent": "[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36]",
      "requestParameters": {
        "list-type": "2",
        "bucketName": "marketplace-logs",
        "encoding-type": "url",
        "max-keys": "100",
        "prefix": "",
        "delimiter": "/",
        "Host": "marketplace-logs.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "responseElements": null,
      "additionalEventData": {
        "SignatureVersion": "SigV4",
        "CipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "bytesTransferredIn": 0,
        "AuthenticationMethod": "AuthHeader",
        "x-amz-id-2": "CbL2Rxnc1vji9VNOpySFifRpYI8S2Try7/J71wAGV5WZ3HGEv9UANDgHpV3TMFGWKOqQ72WiXXXX",
        "bytesTransferredOut": 716
      },
      "requestID": "6B5AA70ED67EXXXX",
      "eventID": "654eb15e-bd64-4b4d-97b7-362f1f21XXXX",
      "readOnly": true,
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
          "ARNPrefix": "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/"
        },
        {
          "accountId": "65728044XXXX",
          "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
          "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs"
        }
      ],
      "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
      "managementEvent": false,
      "recipientAccountId": "65728044XXXX",
      "eventCategory": "Data"
    }
```

Please help to make it work?

Comment: And to confirm s3 browser is using IAM credentials that have permission to get the object?

Comment: Yes ... its a chrome extension which requires access key/secret key/bucket name/region name

Comment: Could you clarify. So there is an IAM user which you've created for some browser extension. You loaded the secret IAM keys to the extension. The user has this policy attached. The policy denies if the IP is wrong. What about a policy which allows the access? If you have only Deny, how would the IAM user get permissions to access the bucket?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the query, Yes there is an IAM user which have this policy and we loaded extension with the IAM keys. The policy denies only if the user tries to access the bucket other than the listed public IP. It is able to access in case we switch it to "Allow/IpAddress" combination but then it is able to access bucket only when I am not connected to VPN. Basically lets say my IP without VPN is 12.XX.XX.XX/32 and with VPN is 13.XX.XX.XX/32. so if i change the policy to Allow/IpAddress:12.XX then it works but when I change it to Allow/IpAddress:13.XX after connecting to VPN it doesn't

Comment: And we want to provide that access while the user is connected to VPN only so we are giving public IP of the VPN server in the policy

Comment: combination of Deny/NotIpAddress:12.XX also doesn't work which is strange because the combination of Allow/IpAddress:12.XX was working

Comment: This will only work if you have a specific Allow statement in an IAM Policy attached (directly or indirectly) to the user. AWS IAM implicitly denies everything. You can explicitly allow certain actions. An explicit Deny overrides any convicting Allow, but you need an Allow to enable access in the first place.

Comment: Hello @DennisTraub, Thank you for your suggestion. However, as I said the combi of Allow/IpAddress:13.XX is also not working as 13.XX is the public IP of the VPN server. I am seriously caught up in this simple requirement due to VPN dependency.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, can you activate data event logging for the bucket in AWS CloudTrail? Then try to access objects in the bucket and - after a few minutes - the related Events should show up in the audit trail. Look if you can find any events related to the access to see what exactly is happening and if certain API calls are being allowed or denied. Here's how to log data events with AWS CloudTrail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip @DennisTraub, I will try to test this way

Comment: @DennisTraub I have updated the question with your suggestion. The cloud trail event shows the ListObjects event which is not there in the list of applicable events. Please suggest what else I should try?

Comment: Explicitly allow ListObjects and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with the help of AWS support, we were able to restrict the S3 bucket access only via the VPN connection. Actually, the fact that VPN connections would always be terminated at AWS VPC belonging to the customer account. Therefore below are the conditions which needed to be replaced for this restricted access for the requests generated from VPC endpoint or VPC only. To do that, we can either use

```
"Condition": {
   "StringNotEquals": {
        "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-013cab36cf79XXXXX"
    }
 }
```

OR

```
"Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
         "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-0ba7f2c82a70XXXXX"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the browser extension needs more permissions. The AWS CloudTrail log indicates that the browser is trying to call `s3:ListObjects`. Add this action to the policy and try again.

Comment: Hi @DennisTraub,

I have updated the question with working and non-working scenario with the same rights in the IAM policy. One thing I noticed that when I mentioned my personal IP range in the policy ... the same IP was coming in the data event log but when I mentioned the VPN server IP range in the policy ... private VPC IP range was coming in the data event log instead of the public VPN IP range. 

Why is it taking the private VPC IP range when connected to VPN instead of Public IP ... moreover, I have tried to mention the private VPC Ip range in the policy as well but that doesn't work

Comment: Hi @DennisTraub ... any more suggestions pls?